# TP-Link Archer T4U Plus driver

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb-drive

I can't find a driver for this adapter model

Answer (score 0):

TP-Link does not provide any official drivers for Linux-based operating systems. They do have [a download page for the T4U](https://www.tp-link.com/support/download/archer-t4u/#Driver), but the kernel support is limited to 2.6.18 to 4.11. Newer kernels are not at all supported.

That said, you *may* be able to get by with one of the open drivers. This will be 100% dependent on the chipset in your T4u, though.

If your network adapter is using the `RTL8812AU` chipset, then [this driver from thelinuxguy](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8812au-dkms-git/) should work for you.

If you have a European model, which *may* use the `RTL8822A` chipset, then you'll need to find something that works. Unfortunately I do not have any experience with that specific chipset, so do not know where you can find a driver.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/f723b966d5f42094619f9c1048c7838b
For tp-link archer t4u plus v1.0 (European edition I suppose) this solution worked for me on Ubuntu.